# ActiveDirectory search with full name

Tags: active-directory

I am attempting to search active directory based on a full name of 'LAST,FIRST MIDDLEINITIAL' The problem is, these are three seperate fields in AD, but I have only a single string to search with. Is there a way, using active directory to, to search on combined fields similar to the way it can be done in SQL? 
ex in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbltest WHERE (Last + ',' + First + ' ' + MiddleI) = 'LAST,FIRST MIDDLEI'
```

Something like below in active directory perhaps?:

```
"(sn+','+givenname+' '+initials = LAST,FIRST MIDDLEI)"
```

Comment: Searching AD by name is generally a bad idea, it is entirely arbitrary. All of your users could have different name fields, or all the same or no name at all. I suggest if you can use one of the custom fields in AD to store something unique about each person such as an employee id.

Comment: @Ashigore I don't normally do name search, but in this case all I have is 'LAST,FIRST MIDDLE' so I'm forced to search by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the AccountManagement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace you can do something like:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, FQDC))
{
    UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(context);

    up.GivenName = First;
    up.MiddleName = MiddleI;
    up.Surname = Last;

    PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
    ps.QueryFilter = up;

    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindOne();

    if (results != null) ...
}
```

If you're using SDS with say a DirectorySearcher you would set the filter property:

```
searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectclass=user)(lastname={0})(firstname={1})(middlename={2}))", Last, First, MiddleI);
```

Comment: This seems to split the name into three fields, first, middle, and last. I want to search as if they were one filed 'LAST,FIRST MIDDLE'

Comment: Unless you're storing the name like that in some other attribute (say DisplayName) then you won't be able to search that way.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that wasn't the answer, but I suppose we don't always get what we want.